# Find rectangle vertices given its coordinates, width and height

Tags: javascript, math, vertices

I have a rectangle, that could be rotated. At every rotation, I need to to know its new top, left, right and bottom vertices.

[image: Before]
[image: After rotate]
I've tried to loop through the new rectangle coordinates, but I want to calculate vertices without a loop to reduce execution time

At first, I calculate new rotated coordinates and then I find new vertices.

```
rotatedRectCorners(element, center, angle) {
    const theta = (Math.PI / 180) * angle
    const ox = center.x
    const oy = center.y
    const xAx = Math.cos(theta)  // x axis x
    const xAy = Math.sin(theta)  // x axis y
    const x = element.left - ox  // move rectangle onto origin
    const y = element.top - oy

    return {
        topLeft: {
            x: x * xAx - y * xAy + ox,   // Get the top left rotated position
            y: x * xAy + y * xAx + oy
        },
        topRight: {
            x: (x + element.width) * xAx - y * xAy + ox,   // Get the top right rotated position
            y: (x + element.width) * xAy + y * xAx + oy
        },
        bottomRight: {
            x: (x + element.width) * xAx - (y + element.height) * xAy + ox,   // Get the bottom right rotated position
            y: (x + element.width) * xAy + (y + element.height) * xAx + oy
        },
        bottomLeft: {
            x: x * xAx - (y + element.height) * xAy + ox,   // Get the bottom left rotated position
            y: x * xAy + (y + element.height) * xAx + oy
        }
    }
}

rectVertices(element, center, angle) {
    const corners = rotatedRectCorners(element, center, angle)
    const vertices = {
        top: {x: 0, y: 0},
        left: {x: 0, y: 0},
        right: {x: 0, y: 0},
        bottom: {x: 0, y: 0}
    }
    let maxX = null
    let minX = null
    let minY = null
    let maxY = null
    each(corners, (corner) => {
        if (maxX === null) {
            maxX = corner.x
            vertices.right = corner
        }
        if (minX === null) {
            minX = corner.x
            vertices.left = corner
        }
        if (minY === null) {
            minY = corner.y
            vertices.top = corner
        }
        if (maxY === null) {
            maxY = corner.y
            vertices.bottom = corner
        }
        if (corner.y > maxY) {
            maxY = corner.y
            vertices.bottom = corner
        }
        if (corner.x > maxX) {
            maxX = corner.x
            vertices.right = corner
        }
        if (corner.x < minX) {
            minX = corner.x
            vertices.left = corner
        }
        if (corner.y < minY) {
            minY = corner.y
            vertices.top = corner
        }
    })

    return vertices
}
```

Comment: Without a loop? Complex computations need algorithms like a loop otherwise why use a program? Using loops is what reduces the times or at least properly written ones.

Comment: @zer00ne, I believe that there should be a math solution

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BohdanVovchuck you're right in that this sort of problem can be solved with matrix  multiplication, but in order to implement matrix multiplication in javascript, you're going to need a loop. zer00ne is right, loops aren't automatically inefficient.

Comment: If you're intention is to improve the execution time then you could improve the `rotatedRectCorners` function by storing the product calculations (e.g. x * xAx) in an intermediate variable, at present each one is calculated twice before a result is returned. You can also reduce the number of conditionals in `rectVertices` by half e.g. if (maxX === null || corner.x > maxX) { maxX = corner.x; vertices.right = corner } This will reduce the number of instructions the processor needs to execute but the speed improvement will be in fractions of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Let number rectangle vertices from top left corner in clockwise direction. We can see that V[0] is the leftmost vertex in angle range `0..Pi/2` (90 degrees, angle in CCW direction), V[1] becomes the leftmost one in angle range `Pi/2..Pi` and so on.

So we can reconsile two arrays cyclically corresponding to rotation angle

```
V[0]    V[1]    V[2]    V[3]   
           <==>                      //small angle
left    top     right  bottom


V[2]    V[3]     V[0]    V[1]   
           <==>                     //angle in range 180..270 (Pi..3Pi/2)
left    top     right  bottom




left_index = angle / 90   //integer division if possible in JS
top_index = (1 + angle / 90) % 4 
right_index = (2 + angle / 90) % 4 
bottom_index = (3 + angle / 90) % 4
```

Not that in any case you have to calculate vertices coordinates (much more time)

Comment: I've got it. Smart idea!